# jQueryMobile and javascript file inclusion: potential risks

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a jQueryMobile application with multiple single-pages, linked together.
Some of these pages use common javascript files. So I currently import those javascripts only within pages that need them. For example:

Page A -> include fileutils.js and has a link to Page B
Page B -> include fileutils.js

The user clicks on Page B from Page A. Is there the risk of importing fileutils.js multiple time and execute its code multiple times too?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the js of course will be executed every time you load a page, but the user will download the script just once (setting some proper response header) loading it from the cache after the first request

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to be worry. Let me explain you how jQuery Mobile works.

What you have is called multi **`HTML`** page template. In this case only initial **`HTML`** can have more then one **`data-role="page"`** page inside, every other subsequent page can have only one **`data-role="page"`** page inside.

One first page is initialized it is fully loaded into the DOM. That **`HTML`** page becomes a skeleton for a future page loading. Because it is fully loaded it can hold more then one **`data-role="page"`** page inside.

When next page is initialized jQuery Mobile will strip everything and load only **`data-role="page"`** content. Everything else is going to be discarded, including the HEAD content. Even more only first **`data-role="page"`** page is going to be loaded, which means you can't have more then one **`data-role="page"`** page inside.

This means that if you have a custom javascript inside subsequent pages it must be inside **`data-role="page"`** div, otherwise jQuery Mobile will discard it.

This works in case standard **`AJAX`** loading is on, which is a default state. If **`AJAX`** loading is turned off jQuery Mobile will load pages like they are normal pages and every subsequent page will replace previous page in the DOM.

Regarding your other question, because of this architecture same js files will never initialize more then once. But there's another problem you will need to be careful with event binding. Because of this specific architecture events can be bind more then once. So you will need to use pageinit page event to initialize your javascript per page. There are several more solutions to this problem but I will describe them only if you want.

Comment: Thank you Gajotres. I'm aware of including custom javascript inside data-role="page" div, because jQM works exactly as you said. To get rid of potential multiple event  bindings, I normally make calls like this: $(selector).unbind().bind(...). So, can you confirm that there are no big downsides with this architecture?

Comment: I can confirm that there are no big downsides with that architecture.